# Money zellied to me with bank confirmation then boa riskmanagement

Tags: financial-literacy

I recently opened a new account with Bank of America, where I haven't had an account in about 10 years. I needed help fixing my car so my mother sent me money via Zelle and I got a confirmation verification text from BOA. Later I tried to login to my account and couldn't. I tried several different ways and no success.  So I called BOA, where a CS rep told me my account was closed by risk management and that the money was never received from Zelle. They then tried to pass me on to risk management but I was too upset. So I tried calling Zelle where you really can't talk to anyone.

What do I do?

Comment: Please don't joke about committing a crime. I'm not sure what you are looking for. Obviously you need to talk to risk management, once you are less upset. What other possible answer do you expect?

Comment: You opened an account and immediately had money transferred to you.  BoA Risk Management thought that was suspicious.  I don't know why, but they did.  You need to call and talk to them.  **Calmly.**  Being "to[sic] upset" and wanting to "hack them" **won't get you anywhere**.

Answer (score 10):

Bank of America is the party that closed your account, so you need to talk to Bank of America. Specifically, you should speak with the department that they tried to transfer you to in the first place—risk management.